# IdP as the master session

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, keycloak, single-page-application

## Background

I'm trying implement a [browser-based login](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/#Authorization-Flow-for-Native-Apps-Using-the-Browser) for a native mobile app from an existing Single Page Application. It uses `WebView` to render the SPA and it uses Keycloak OIDC as its Identity Provider.

The SPA and IdP is located in completely different domain and authentication is done by redirecting to the SPA domain after a successful login and retrieving the active session (cookie) from IdP domain in one of the SPA's server. The authentication check is achieved by using keycloak middleware which I believe is the [protect.js](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/main/middleware/protect.js#L35)

**Summary**:

1. Perform Login -> auth.idp.com
2. Redirect -> best.app.com
3. Is Login? -> best.app.com/login

   - Does auth.idp.com session exists?
4. User is logged in, redirect -> best.app.com

   - Token is passed in the URL and is stored only in memory
   - Token is used to establish WebSocket connection

## Issue

Based from [the spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc8252.html#section-5), the authorization should happen in the browser / in-app browser, and authorization code must be passed via custom URL scheme. Having that in mind, the SPA that resides in the `WebView` of native mobile app will never establish a session from IdP's domain since this will be delegated from the browser which is on a different process and obviously using a different cookie store than on `WebView` in the mobile app, which makes our existing solution to break because it is relying on the IdP's domain cookie.
[image: browser-based login]

## Proposed Solution

The issue I described above can be mitigated by cutting the reliance on IdP's session and by managing the SPA's own session, which basically means storing the token persistently that can be obtained from the IdP (which the current solution doesn't do).

(I don't want to detail much of the solution since I just want to focus first on the concept of storing the token. I think it's better for me to put this in a separate discussion if someone is interested)

## Opinion

1. It seems like the current implementation doesn't really follow the best practice for OIDC flow but somehow, Keycloak has made some middleware to remove the need to use these tokens (authorization code, id token, and access token)
2. Relying on IdP's session when implementing SPA or non-web apps seems like not an option, because there is no way to obtain the cookie without reloading the page and provided that IdP session exists in the same cookie store as the SPA.
3. Redirecting to the IdP's session is not a good user experience for SPA. See the same sentiment here but it seems it does not have any answer: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-October/007937.html

## Question

1. With regards to my proposed solution, i.e., storing the token retrieved from IdP, is there any security flaw or something non-industry standard it's going to introduce? If so, what are those?
2. Is it typical for OIDC flow to rely on IdP's session (cookie) to check if user is logged in or not?
3. If answer from #2 is NO, is that authentication flow specific for Keycloak only or does it exists for other IdP as well?
4. If answer from #2 is YES, is it common for IAM solution to programmatically check if the IdP domain contains a valid session (cookie)?
5. Is the current implementation flawed knowing we are aiming for SPA?

Comment: https://darutk.medium.com/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660

from what I can tell the answer to number 2 is yes.  But I'm not very knowledgeable on this topic. But I think these Diagrams help us understand OIDC easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How does Keycloak handle sessions?

If you're using the default Keycloak middleware in your server and use [keycloak.protect()](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/main/keycloak.js#L188) for protecting endpoints, it checks on the `request.session['keycloak-token']` which contains the `access_token` that was created during the token request after user login. If this exist and valid, it means user will not be redirected to Keycloak login page.

### How does Keycloak create sessions?

1. Providing username and password which can be done manually using Keycloak's login page.
2. **Cookies** - if you pass valid cookies that are recognized by Keycloak, i.e., `KEYCLOAK_SESSION, KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY, ...`, a session will automatically be created.

### How to access protected resources?

When using the `keycloak-connect` client adapters, you can access protected resources if the user agent (browser/app), has a valid session in your server **OR** if the request contains valid `Authorization` header.

### Standard Solution

1. Access protected resource via `Authorization` header and use `access_token` which the [keycloak.protect()](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/main/keycloak.js#L188) also accepts. You can obtain this token in a standard way using `Chrome Custom Tabs` for Android and `ASWebAuthenticationSession` for iOS. You can also use `AppAuth` ([iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS), [Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android)) to lessen your work.
2. Store the `refresh_token` and `access_token` from native mobile and inject this in the HTTP request of `WebView` if possible.
3. Have a way to check for `access_token` validity and use `refresh_token` to request for a new one. If requesting for a new one fails, i.e., the authorization server verifies it's not valid anymore, that means users would need to re login again.

By using the standard solution I have proposed above, you should not need to create a band-aid solution for your issue. Hope this helps anyone that have faced similar issue.